# Hartl Chapter 6 Exercises

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am new to rails- having issues with the end of the Michael Hartl rails tutorial, chapter 6 exercises.

Here are the results of my test:

```
    FAIL["test_email_should_not_be_too_long", UserTest, 2015-12-17 15:58:31 +0000]
 test_email_should_not_be_too_long#UserTest (1450367911.89s)
        Expected true to be nil or false
        test/models/user_test.rb:37:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

Here is my user_test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end


  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end


  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = ""
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end


  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end


  test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" *51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end


  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"

    assert_not @user.valid?
  end


  test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
      @user.email = valid_address
      assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
    end
  end

  test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example.
                       foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"  
    end 
  end

  test "email addresses should be unique" do
    duplicate_user = @user.dup
    duplicate_user.email = @user.email.upcase
    @user.save
    assert_not duplicate_user.valid?
  end

  test "email addresses should be saved as lower-case" do
    mixed_case_email = "Foo@ExAMPle.CoM"
    @user.email = mixed_case_email
    @user.save
    assert_equal mixed_case_email.downcase, @user.reload.email
  end

  test "password should have a minimum length" do
    @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end
end
```

And here is my user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is a small bug in your models/user.rb file. If the name has a maximum length explicitly listed, the email should as well.